# How to programmatically animate an ImageView

Tags: android, android-animation, scaletransform

I am trying to animate an ImageView when the said image view is clicked.

Specifically I want the size of the ImageView gets bigger (say .20 bigger) and the immediately shrink back to its original size).

So far I have been experimenting with this code with no luck.

```
// thumbLike is the imageView I would like to animate.
button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        ScaleAnimation scaleAnim = new ScaleAnimation(1.0f, 2.5f, 1.0f, 2.5f,
                                    Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f,
                                    Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f);
        scaleAnim.setInterpolator(new LinearInterpolator());
        scaleAnim.setDuration(1500);
        thumbLike.startAnimation(scaleAnim);
        thumbLike.setAnimation(null);
    }
});
```

Can anyone suggest me with a possible solution?

**Edit #1**

It is working through XML as answered by Hardik4560:

```
// finally i use this code to execute the animation
Animation animationScaleUp = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.scale_up);
Animation animationScaleDown = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.scale_down);

AnimationSet growShrink = new AnimationSet(true);
growShrink.addAnimation(animationScaleUp);
growShrink.addAnimation(animationScaleDown);
thumbLike.startAnimation(growShrink);
```

and the XML

```
SCALE_UP
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/linear_interpolator">
    <scale
        android:fromXScale="1.0"
        android:toXScale="1.5"
        android:fromYScale="1.0"
        android:toYScale="1.5"
        android:pivotX="50%"
        android:pivotY="50%"
        android:duration="1000" />
</set>

SCALE_DOWN
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/linear_interpolator">
    <scale
        android:fromXScale="1.5"
        android:toXScale="1.0"
        android:fromYScale="1.5"
        android:toYScale="1.0"
        android:pivotX="50%"
        android:pivotY="50%"
        android:duration="1000" />
</set>
```

ps: this is awkward, since I already accepted an answer. I am trying to combine between @tharkbad and @Hardik4560 's answers yet now the way it animates does not look smooth.

during the scale_up animation, it kinda look like being "skip" to the end of animation and then immediately starting scale_down animation. I guess I have to play around with it a bit.

Comment: is it producing any error ?

Comment: No it is not. It's just not doing anything.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I use this to achieve popin popout effect,

See if its of any use to you

Pop Out.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/bounce_interpolator"    >
    <scale
        android:pivotX="50%"
        android:pivotY="50%"
        android:fromXScale="0.5"
        android:fromYScale="0.5"
        android:toXScale="1.0"
        android:toYScale="1.0"
        android:duration="500" />

</set>
```

Pop In

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/bounce_interpolator"    >
    <scale
        android:pivotX="50%"
        android:pivotY="50%"
        android:fromXScale="1.0"
        android:fromYScale="1.0"
        android:toXScale="0.0"
        android:toYScale="0.0"
        android:duration="500" />

</set>
```

Comment: Hi, yeah it's working now. Thanks. I am unable to accept your answer at the moment

Comment: No worries Sir. Happy that it helped. May be later you accept :)

Comment: @username55, Wait for 5 minutes, then you can accept this answer.

Comment: Hi could you post a example of the java code on how to implement the xml based animation?

Comment: pop = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(mAppContext, R.anim.pop); and v.startAnimation(pop);

Answer (score 20):

If you want to implement this without XML you could do so as follows

```
final float growTo = 1.2f;
final long duration = 1200;

ScaleAnimation grow = new ScaleAnimation(1, growTo, 1, growTo, 
                                         Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f,
                                         Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f);
grow.setDuration(duration / 2);
ScaleAnimation shrink = new ScaleAnimation(growTo, 1, growTo, 1,
                                           Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f,
                                           Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f);
shrink.setDuration(duration / 2);
shrink.setStartOffset(duration / 2);
AnimationSet growAndShrink = new AnimationSet(true);
growAndShrink.setInterpolator(new LinearInterpolator());
growAndShrink.addAnimation(grow);
growAndShrink.addAnimation(shrink);
thumbLike.startAnimation(growAndShrink);
```

Of course, you could also use [NineOldAndroids](http://nineoldandroids.com/) and use the new animation methods.

I think your original error is this line, it removes the animation you just started from the view again.

```
thumbLike.setAnimation(null);
```

Comment: @Thrakbad How can I do like only when it's done with the animation then perform something else?

Comment: You would need to add an `AnimationListener` (or `AnimatorListener` for NineOldAndroids/the new Animations) to your animation.

Comment: Works like charm. Thank you @Thrakbad

Comment: thanx hepled me

Answer (score 0):

I created the same animation using kotlin:

**Repo:** https://github.com/David-Hackro/Bounce-Animation

You need create your element and extend of anything (ImageView,Button etc)
in my case y created a class named `BounceWidget`

[image]

*Add element in xml*

```
<hackro.tutorials.com.bounceWidget.widget.BounceWidget
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

*Add element programmatically*

```
val xpp = resources.getXml(R.xml.bouncewidget)
val attr = Xml.asAttributeSet(xpp)
val layout : LinearLayout = findViewById(R.id.layout)
val octocat1 : BounceWidget = BounceWidget(this,attr)

//you can change this values and have default values

//octocat1.id_resource(R.mipmap.bounceimage) // change image --> default : R.mipmap.ic_launcher
//octocat1.positionX = 1 //position X starting --> default : 0
//octocat1.positionY = 1 //position Y starting--> default : 0
//octocat1.velocityX = 1 //Velocity X --> default : 20
//octocat1.velocityY = 1 //Velocity Y --> default : 15

octocat1.layoutParams = LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT)

layout.addView(octocat1)
```