# How can I implement animation for ImageViews in an Android service?

Tags: android, android-service, android-animation

I have found that the code available for animating image views like here:
[How to programatically animate an ImageView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20991764/how-to-programatically-animate-an-imageview)

doesn't work when the ImageView is created inside a service and not an activity. How to then animate ImageViews in a windowmanager in an Android service?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Android Service are intended to run in background. They do not have access for UI elements. For example, inside a service, you cannot display toast messages or progress dialog or Alertdialog or any UI element which is visible to the user.

So, basically, you cannot do UI operations inside a service.

If you want to do animations inside an activity, which takes long time, you can use threads.

Comment: I thought FB chat heads worked using a WindowManager in a Service? If not, do you know how else can that be implemented?
Thank you for your answer.